# Is it allowed to believe on the personality told on the basis of stars like Aquarius, Cancer etc

Tags: halal-haram

I read a  personality description which was based on my star and it was matching with my personality.  I want to ask that is it allowed in Islam to read and believe these kind of descriptions ?

Comment: Basically horoscopes are written in a way which makes the majority feel it matches with their day or personality. Read about how they are written, a good subject would be reading about "cold reading". Matching this technique with a star or something is just a trick.

Answer (score 2):

It's haram (forbidden).  Astrology and horoscopes are considered among "fortune telling", "soothsaying", etc.  These are considered as contradicting *None in the heavens and earth knows the unseen except Allah* ([Qur'an 27:65](https://quran.com/27/65)), and stricter scholars interpret belief in astrology as a form of kufr.

*Believing Fortunetellers and Astrologers* is major sin #46 in *Major Sins* by [Al-Dhahabi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Dhahabi) ([pdf](http://www.islamtomorrow.com/books/major_sins/majorSins.pdf)).  He lists the hadith (listed as "Reported by Ahamd and AI-Hakim"):

> Whoever goes to a psychic (`Arraf) or a fortuneteller and believes what he says disbelieves in what has been revealed to Muhammad.

A similar hadith is listed at [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/32863).  There's other ahadith quoted in various fatawa: [SeekersHub](http://seekershub.org/ans-blog/2010/12/07/is-it-permissible-to-believe-in-astrology-and-horoscopes/), [albalagh.net](http://albalagh.net/qa/0094.shtml), and [IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=5827), all firmly against astrology.

---

Also [astrology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrology) is scientifically a load of rubbish:

> Where astrology has made falsifiable predictions, it has been falsified.
>   <sub>[Astrology and science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrology_and_science), Wikipedia</sub>